# Row terminators for text files used for bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

I had the following code working, but the source (vendor) creating the text file changed and now the command inserts 0 rows, with no error message.

Previous working code:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT CSU_bookslip_purch_daily_temp
            FROM ''C:\SSIS\BOOKSLIP\PARSED\Input.txt''
            WITH
                (
                   FIRSTROW = 2,
                   FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                   ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + CHAR(10) + ''')'

EXEC(@cmd)
```

I tried changing it to:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)

SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT CSU_bookslip_purch_daily_temp
FROM ''C:\SSIS\BOOKSLIP\PARSED\Input.txt''
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
EXEC(@cmd)
```

Comment: Please provide example data from Input.txt. Scrub it its sensitive data and it can be just a few rows. I'm guessing the file is no longer comma delimited or the row terminator is no longer a line feed (\n).

Answer (score 4):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#specifying-n-as-a-row-terminator-for-bulk-import

You need to specify the New Line `\n` ROWTERMINATOR like this:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue then Install Notepad++

Notepad++>> Edit >> EOL Conversion >> Windows Format

The Notepad++ steps are needed if the file is generated on a non-windows system now since the vendor changed.

Also, for this to work its important the the file you are importing and the destination table have the exact same columns. If the table has columns not in the csv you can get this error. And vice versa if the file has columns the table doesn't have.

Comment: in windows line breaks are `\r\n` or `char(13)+char(10)`, so OP’s code should still split rows, only with a superfluous carriage return at the end.

Comment: Will be super helpful to see example file. Going off very limited information here.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say – and this is really something – that specifying `\n` splits rows at `\r\n`.

> When you specify \n as a row terminator for bulk import, or implicitly use the default row terminator, bcp and the BULK INSERT statement expect a carriage return-line feed combination (CRLF) as the row terminator. If your source file uses a line feed character only (LF) as the row terminator - as is typical in files generated on Unix and Linux computers - use hexadecimal notation to specify the LF row terminator. For example, in a BULK INSERT statement:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#specifying-terminators-for-bulk-import

I think that’s pretty amazing. So maybe try the hex code instead?

But really we would need to know the actual row terminator in the input file. To find out, you might open the file in Notepad++ or similar and turn on special characters (usually a button with a pilcrow on it).